# How to optimize slow Mysql SELECT queries?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance

Here is my query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18
FROM table1
WHERE col1= 'val' and col7='Y' and col16='203' OR col16='201' order by col4 desc
```

I don't know what is making this query slow,
whether it's the `order by` ,or the where clauses...

Properely added the index also, but it's still slow.

I'am using JSP + STRUTS + EJB2.0 + MYSQL.
The table1 has more than half million records.
How can I optimize the query or what are the other possibilities to improve the speed of execution?

table structure

```
col1                varchar(20) NO  PRI 
col2                varchar(50) NO  PRI 
col3                varchar(50) YES     [NULL]
col4                varchar(20) YES     [NULL]
col5                varchar(6)  YES     [NULL]
col6                varchar(20) YES     [NULL]
col7                varchar(1)  YES     [NULL]
col8               mediumtext   YES     [NULL]
col9              mediumtext    YES     [NULL]
col10             mediumtext    YES     [NULL]
col11              mediumtext   YES     [NULL]
col12              mediumtext   YES     [NULL]
col13               mediumtext  YES     [NULL]
col14             mediumtext    YES     [NULL]
col15               mediumtext  YES     [NULL]
col16               varchar(20) YES     [NULL]
col17            varchar(50)    YES     [NULL]
col18             varchar(5)    YES     [NULL]
col19              varchar(5)   YES     [NULL]
col20               varchar(5)  YES     [NULL]
col21                  text YES     [NULL]
col 22                  text    YES     [NULL]
col23              text YES     [NULL]
col24              varchar(5)   YES     [NULL]
col25              int(11)  YES     [NULL]
```

Comment: Table definition,explain plan

Comment: How many lines this query is supposed to return ? What makes your query slow is the `order by`, not really the `where` condition

Comment: its returns all those records which satisfy the conditions from half million records

Comment: And how many records normally satisfy the conditions?

Comment: if you take 500000 records, then 
around 10000 records - for condition  col1= 'val'
out of 10000 records 7000 records for condition col7='Y'
out of 7000 records  1000 records for condition col16='209'
out of 6000 records  2000 records for cpndition col16='201'

so the final output will be around 3000 records  approx

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what it is making this query slow, whether order by, or conditions..

Half a million records should fit in memory if they're the usual sort of name, phone nr, email sort of thing (and not documents). So if it's -very- slow, something is very wrong.

> properly added index also,still slow.

Which columns are indexed? You need to index by the column that will filter most effectively. For example, if col2 is the answer to a yes or no question, it won't help to index by that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query -

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18  
FROM table1 
where 
col1= 'val' 
and col2='Y' 
and (col3='203' OR col3='201')
order by col4 desc
```

This will first need a covering index

```
alter table table1 add index search_idx(col1,col2,col3) ;
```

Now to resolve the order by clause you will need to index that as well

```
alter table table1 add index col4_idx(col4) ;
```

Now note that the `or` condition is killer and performace wise its better to convert this to `union all`

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18  
FROM table1 
where 
col1= 'val' 
and col2='Y' 
and col3='203'
union all
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18  
FROM table1 
where 
col1= 'val' 
and col2='Y' 
and col3='201'
order by col4 desc
```

You may use `explain select` for the above queries to analyze the query health.

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: This will not return the same result as the original query, AND takes precedence over OR

Comment: @dnoeth: did you observe that this `union all` is just a split on the first query in this answer?

Comment: In the original query `WHERE col1= 'val' AND col2='Y' AND col3='203' OR col3='201'` which I assume is not correct since without `and ( cond1 or con2)` lead to some unexpected result.

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy: Yep, it's based on the first answer, but the first answer doesn't return the same result set as the OP'S query.

Comment: @dnoeth: OP might unknowingly used that format of query. He already agreed that the suggested query gave a [*desired result*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319746/how-to-optimize-slow-mysql-select-queries/30319861?noredirect=1#comment48735202_30319948)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your WHERE-condition is correct?

AND takes precedence over OR, so

```
where col1= 'val' and col2='Y' and col3='203' OR col3='201'
```

is the same as

```
where (col1= 'val' and col2='Y' and col3='203') OR (col3='201')
```

But you probably want

```
where col1= 'val' and col2='Y' and (col3='203' OR col3='201')
```

**Edit:**
Based on your comment my assumption was wrong and you actually want the original result (Then I would suggest adding parentheses to make it clear). The only possible index in that case would be on `col3` (if it's selective enough).

I don't know if mysql's optimizer is smart enough to access a table using the same index twice, if not you need to UNION ALL two queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18
FROM table1
WHERE col1= 'val' AND col2='Y' AND col3='203'

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7, col8,..,col18
FROM table1
WHERE col3='201'
ORDER BY col4 DESC
```

Edit2:
After the OP edited the question the column names are wrong (`col2` will be `col7` and `col3` will be `col16`)

Comment: where col1= 'val' and col2='Y' and (col3='203' OR col3='201')  will this make any difference?

Comment: Of course, it returns a totally different result. **You** need to know what you actually want.

Comment: the query gives the desired output but the only problem i faced...was its slow output response.

Comment: @vineeth.soman: So all current answer provide no solution to this problem, because they try to optimize the wrong query :-)  Can you provide some info, how many rows are returned by your query and the avg number of rows per value for `col3` (= selectivity)

Comment: if you take 500000 records, then 
around 10000 records - for condition  col1= 'val'
out of 10000 records 7000 records for condition col7='Y'
out of 7000 records  1000 records for condition col16='209'
out of 6000 records  2000 records for cpndition col16='201'

so the final output will be around 3000 records approx

Comment: @vineeth.soman: So try the index on `col16` as described in my answer

Comment: so the query remains same...just have to add an index on col16 ..right?

Comment: @vineeth.soman: Add the index, see if the plan changes, if not try the UNION ALL approach.